# Java Code Error For Leapyear

Tags: java

I'm getting this error message when I try to compile this code, and I'm not sure why because I have if's following my else's. Any help is appreciated:

```
error: 'else' without 'if'
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LeapYear
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int year;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a year:\n[1582] ");
        year= sc.nextInt();

        if (year < 1582);
            System.out.print("Error! \"Calender starts from 1582\".");
        else
        {
            if ((year%4==0 || year%400==0) && (year>1999 || year%   100!=0))
                System.out.println ("A leap year.");
            else
                System.out.println("Not a leap year. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if(year < 1582);   -> if(year < 1582)
you are terminating if with a blank statement by using a semi-colon, so the following else doesn't find a valid 'if' statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ';' at the end of the if line. Your code should be:

```
if (year < 1582)
    System.out.print("Error! \"Calender starts from 1582\".");
else
{
    ....
```

or better:

```
if (year < 1582)
{
    System.out.print("Error! \"Calender starts from 1582\".");
}
else
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an empty body to your `if`. The semicolon can (and does in this case) denote an empty statement.

**tl;dr**

Change

```
if (year < 1582);
```

to remove the semicolon

```
if (year < 1582)
```